# Visiting directories with Scala

Tags: java, scala, path

I'm reading "Scala for the impatient" (second edition) and I'm stucked on how to visit directories (Section 9.7).

I want to open sequentially all files of a directory (excluding folders present in that directory; those files are text files).
The example provided in the book is not straightforward, because it does not explain how to process path objects (java.nio.file.Path)

Here is the example in the book (slightly modified):

```
import java.nio.file._
val dirname: String = "./9_files_and_regular_expressions"
val entries = Files.list(Paths.get(dirname))
entries.toArray // print all the file names and consume the iterator...

val entries = Files.list(Paths.get(dirname))
try {
    entries.forEach(p => process the path p)
  } finally {
    entries.close()
  }
```

Instead of "process the path p", I would like to open the related directories... I saw the documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html , but this package seems very low level... Should I need to convert a path to a file first, and then process this file object?

Are there any simpler way to perform this simple task in Scala (open text files of a directory)?

Comment: See [java.nio.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).  There are many static methods for `Path`.  For example `readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the directory and filter all the Directories inside it and process each file by opening it. Below is simple example

```
  val dirname: String = "/path"

  val files = new File(dirname)

  files.listFiles().filter( !_.isDirectory).map{
    file => process the file 
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Working, thank you! I replaced "process the file" with "io.Source.fromFile(file).mkString" for testing and it works as expected.